# SharePoint 2010 Search is not Crawling .log format files

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

SharePoint 2010 Search is not crawling the Log File Format (.log) file type, I added some new log files (.log) to shared documents. But I cannot search inside them.

I have added file type (log) in File Types page and ran full crawl but unable to search log file content.

The crawl log was showing nothing

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please check crawl loges. 
I did a test and I crawled FileShare with *.log files successfully.
And on Search Result page I was able to find log files.